# Obtaining GPS fix (ORG447X)

Tags: gps, nmea

Folks

I am using ORG447x to obtain GPS fixes.
Whenever I power up my GPS module

Only response I get is 
`$PSRF150,1,*3E`

Even if I have to write a series of input messages
`"$PSRF103,01,00,01,01*24"` --> Query rate for GGL message
`"$PSRF100,1,4800,8,1,0*0E"` --> setting serial port

I have never got any GGL output messages.

Is there any specific initialization routine I need to follow after powering up my GPS module?
Any tips or pointers appreciated
Thanks
*AK*

Comment: How long did you wait? Did you make sure it had a clear view of the sky? It's possible that it just didn't finish initializing. It can take up to 10 minutes if the module has no idea where any satellites are or any idea where it is.